# Trying to set a learnable threshold in Pytorch

Tags: pytorch

I try to set a param that could be learned. I hope this param could be a threshold that could limit the input. If the input is smaller than it ,then will be set as -1e9. If not smaller, then keep its number. In the following code, I want to use this param to be a threshold of MASK , then find the corresponding positions to set that pixels as -1e9.
`class A(nn.Module):
def **init**(self, ):
super().**init**()
self.threshold = nn.Parameter(torch.tensor(0.01, requires_grad=True))

```
def forward(self, x, mask=None):
   
    x = torch.where(mask <= self.threshold,torch.tensor(-1e9).cuda(),x)
   
    return x`
```

But the problem is that THERE IS NO GRAD!
Is there any way for me to achieve what i wanna do ?

I hope the threshold could be updated as the training process

Comment: Use Straight-Through Estimator (STE): def forward(self, x, mask=None):
    # Define the constant gradient for non-differentiable regions
    grad_replace = torch.zeros_like(x)

    # Apply STE
    x = torch.where(mask <= self.threshold, -1e9, x)
    x.register_hook(lambda grad: torch.where(mask <= self.threshold, grad_replace, grad))
    return x

Comment: Thx for your answer, but I am sorry, I follow the way u mentioned like: grad_replace = torch.zeros_like(attn)  # Apply STE
            attn = torch.where(mask <= self.threshold, -1e9, attn)
            attn.register_hook(lambda grad: torch.where(mask <= self.threshold, grad_replace, grad))            But it still dont work. The value of the self.threshold still dont change. And i search the STE method, should I copy the attn's grad value to self.threshold's grad? How should I code to make it?